If a Page's RSC payload is not cached in the Router Cache in Next.js 15, why does it help to place the parent Layout(s) in the Router Cache?
In Next.js 15, the Router Cache caches the RSC payload of Layouts, but not of Pages:

With the Router Cache:

Layouts are cached and reused on navigation (partial rendering).
Loading states are cached and reused on navigation for instant navigation.
Pages are not cached by default, but are reused during browser backward and forward navigation. You can enable caching for page
segments by using the experimental staleTimes config option.


If the browser anyways have to send a request to the server when using a Link to navigate to a new Page, how does it help us that the Layout was cached?
Presumably, the request to the server will send the client an entirely new RSC payload containing the SC tree for the entire route (as well as the JavaScript for the client components), thus defeating the purpose of caching the Layout client side in the Router Cache.
